# hide page number in overleaf

Tags: tables, page-numbering

I m writing a scientific paper using overleaf. I have a large table which fit in a whole page. The problem is the table cover the page number. SO, how i can hide this page number (only for this page)?

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,ulem}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color,soul,siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shadows}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}
\footnotesize
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
  \hline
a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h&e&j&k&l&m \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{bla bla\label{category}}
\end{sidewaystable*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `\thispagestyle{empty}`, but this is just a guess without a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)...

Comment: It works but it hide the previous page or the next page but not the page where the table is

Comment: That's one of the reasons why a MWE would be helpful.

Comment: Probably the table is floating to the next page and the effect of the `\thispagestyle{empty}` is too early. Try doing the `\thispagestyle{empty}` inside the `\begin{table}...\end{table}`. I don't know if it will work because of grouping, but...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, it is not working same effect as outside the tabel

Comment: @bib Then, as samcarter already said, [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `floatpag` package might help:

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,ulem}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color,soul,siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shadows}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{sidewaystable*}
\footnotesize
\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{bla bla\label{category}}
\end{sidewaystable*}


\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Off-topic: please don't load the same package multiple times.

Comment: thank you it is working. But what do you mean by Off-topic: please don't the same package multiple times?

Comment: @bib You are loading packages multiple times, for example `color` and `titlesec`.  This is in the best case unnecessary in the worst case it can cause errors if you use different options. So don't do it.